# Arduino IDE fails on Fedora with arduino-builder error "Parameter 'tools' is mandatory"

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-builder

The `arduino-builder` app when invoked directly with parameter `--tools /usr/bin` works, but the IDE fails with the error in the title for any sketch (including the Blink example).

I've tried adding things to `preferences.txt` like

```
tools.path=/usr/bin
```

And variations, but I keep getting the same failure in the IDE.  This is using a fresh distro package install on Fedora 27 (I did not have this problem previously using Fedora 25).

Comment: I'd be interested to hear whether the official version of the Arduino IDE downloaded from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software also has this issue. I've noticed the Arduino IDE version that is in the package managers is always mucked around with so you will encounter strange bugs like this that don't happen with the official version.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend!!!!! All is working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't understand why this worked, but I found [this comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1435029#c15) in Redhat Bugzilla (it doesn't seem to be a bug report specifically about that...but anyway):

> > Parameter 'tools' is mandatory
> >     [...]
>
> However, if I create the packages directory in ~/.arduino15, compilation now works.
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/.arduino15/packages
> ```

Seemed like an easy thing to try, and voila -- after an hour of fuss.

I do not understand why this is so (nothing ends up in that directory, either) but I'm leaving this in hopes it may save someone else some time.

Comment: Yep, this looks stupid, but works :)

Comment: Yep, worked! Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you posted this. I just updated to Fedora 33 and the latest Arduino IDE to find this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The problem occurs because arduino does not have permission to modify directory in /usr/share/arduino to create tools-builder

All you have to do is navigate to usr/share/arduino create 'tool-builder' directory 
**`sudo mkdir /usr/share/arduino/tools-builder`**

Comment: This is what I needed to do. Fedora 27, arduino IDE 1.8.4

Comment: Ditto for Fedora 32